# System.calloutException You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

Tags: lightning, integration

As per the requirement we have a quick action on lightning and on the load of the lightning quick action we are calling external service and after that updating the object record in future method.

On load of the page when I first click the action its giving me the exception and the after that everything is working fine.

The issue could be salesforce related but I am trying to debug the code.

### this method is used for call out

// This method generates the token and returns it

```
public static IAMResponse generateToken(WebserviceConfiguration__c oConfiguration){
    IAMResponse response;
    HttpRequest oRequest = new HttpRequest();
    oRequest.setEndpoint('callout:'+oConfiguration.NamedCredentials__c);
    oRequest.setMethod('POST');
    oRequest.setTimeout(Integer.valueOf(oConfiguration.CalloutTimeOut__c));
    oRequest.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    Http http = new Http();
    // send the request
    HttpResponse oResponse = http.send(oRequest);

    if(oResponse.getStatusCode() == 200){
        system.debug('statusCode'+oResponse.getStatusCode());
        Map<String,Object> result = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(oResponse.getBody());
        updateCurrentConfiguration(String.ValueOf(result.get('access_token')),
                                   Integer.valueOf(result.get('expires_in')),
                                   oConfiguration.Id);
 }else{
        Map<String,Object> result = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(oResponse.getBody());
        response = new IAMResponse(NULL,
                                   System.Label.IAM_APIErrorPrefix+' '+result.get('error_description')+' '+System.Label.IAM_APIErrorSuffix);
        Error_Log__c oError = new Error_Log__c(Method_Name__c='generateToken',
                                               Class__c='IAM_Authorization',
                                               Error_Message__c=String.valueOf(result.get('error')),
                                               Error_Type__c=String.valueOf(result.get('error_description')));
        insert oError;
    }

    return response;
}
```

// method call to update the object

```
 @future
public static void updateCurrentConfiguration(String access_token,Integer expires_in,String oConfigurationId){
    WebserviceConfiguration__c oConfiguration = [select id,
                                                 AccessToken__c,
                                                 TokenExpirationInterval__c,
                                                 TokenValidTill__c,
                                                 LastRun__c from WebserviceConfiguration__c where Id=: oConfigurationId];
    oConfiguration.AccessToken__c = encryptToken(access_token);
    oConfiguration.TokenExpirationInterval__c = expires_in;
    oConfiguration.TokenValidTill__c = 
    System.Now().addSeconds(expires_in);
    oConfiguration.LastRun__c = System.Now();

    Database.SaveResult oDSR = Database.Update(oConfiguration);
    List<Database.SaveResult> dsrList = new List<Database.SaveResult>();
    dsrList.add(oDSR);
    system.debug('dsrList'+dsrList);
    if(!ExceptionHelper.processSaveResult(dsrList,'IAM_Authorization','generateToken','WebserviceConfiguration__c')){
        system.debug('#error'+System.Label.IAM_DMLErrorMessage);
    }

}
```

Comment: provide apex code, so that we can help you. and line, where this exception is throwing

Comment: Depending on the order of operations, this can happen. We'd need to see your component's JavaScript to help debug the issue.

Comment: This is not enough code context to troubleshoot the problem. What happens *before* you make the callout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is fixed now ,according to document when you call future method it create a job that implicitly .
Thats why it happend as a solution i change the flow and execeuted the DML at last of all the callout.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you need to redirect after that update is done before you make the callout to complete the transaction flow. There is not really enough code in your example, however, this is typically the error that you would get if you perform a DML operation before a callout is made and you have not redirected which would commit the changes. This one article [HERE](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000Xh0jQAC) has an interesting approach as well.

**Knowledge Article:** https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326129&type=1&mode=1

**Documentation (Testing):** https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing_dml.htm?search_text=Callout

Comment: The update method I am calling it's a future method.

Comment: I think i got the error , after the callout object updation is done in Future method than again we have a callout for other service , may be there is something failing because of DML.

Comment: have you tried to make a call to refreshView in your component upon your response from your callout?

Comment: That would not help as when getting callout exception , no status will return on the component side but blank.

Comment: Have you considered a catch for your callout exception so that you know what step to take next?